# wp_insert_post featured image from library

Tags: attachments, wp-insert-post

I know there are a lot of posts about it, but I don't want to upload a URL image to the library, I already have the image in the library and its IP. How can I use it with `wp_insert_post`?

Comment: Henry, please always provide your research in your questions. And please don't use the generic [tag:php] tag. Nearly everything is about PHP somehow on this site. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I really didn't want to bother you. I was used to stackoverflow, where the php tag is useful. I'll make better questions in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `set_post_thubmnail()`.

After you inserted your post, just call this one, and you are ready to go.

```
$yourpostid = wp_insert_post( $args ); // Define the post in the args first
set_post_thumbnail( $yourpostid, $thumbnail_id ); // set the ID of your thumbnail to be the featured image of your newly created post.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm. Thank you for helping me again.